# get Sku for item with custom options

Tags: orders, sku, items

I'm adding some tracking code on my order confirmation page. But I'd like it to change what it reports for items with custom options.

Below is what my PHP code looks like now to get the variables (i stripped out the javascript echoes for simplicity). And this works.

But I've got a bunch of items on the site that have custom options, so they're reporting (for example) as three separate skus *12345-red*, *12345-green*, *12345-blue*.

And we'd prefer to strip off the custom option info, and just have the single parent sku of *12345*.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());

$items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    $_sku = $item->getSku();
    $_itemprice = $item->getPrice();
    $_itemqty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
}
```

What call do I make instead of `$item->getSku();` to get the sku without the custom-options info attached to it?

Comment: `$item->getProduct()->getSku()`? Or maybe `preg_replace('/-.*$/', '', $item->getSku());`

Comment: Unfortunately, the custom options aren't something I can find/replace out. Too many different options. (I wasn't involved in the product setup.) I think I need to do something along the lines of `if $item->getParentItem()` - but I'm not quite sure. Still working it out.

Comment: The `$item->getProduct()->getSku()` snippet doesn't work either?

Comment: ... Actually, that does seem to work. It *looked* like  `$item->getProduct()->getSku();` & `$item->getSku();` were showing the same thing. But we can chalk that up to user error (i.e. I didn't clear the cache when testing earlier.)  Write that up into an actual answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$item->getProduct()->getSku()` :)

Cheers